# In Garry's Mod, is there any way to stand on a moving object?

Tags: garrys-mod

I've been struggling to create contraptions in Garry's Mod lately simply because I have tendency to want to be moving around on a flying vehicle that is also moving around. Try as I may I can never get this to work, as I often end up falling through the base of the flying vehicle, get killed by the objects on the vehicle, or simply come off the edge.

Is there any way to avoid this? Just to be able to stand still would be great for everything from trains to space stations to aircraft!

If it can't be done in vanilla GMod, I'd be happy to take addon suggestions, or ideas for a lua script if none exist.

Comment: Weld any seat to the vehicle. If you consider getting wiremod then you can use a pod controller, where keystrokes that you perform while in the seat can be registered in circuits to do things like turn on jets and whatnot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, there's now a new tool called the gravity hull stool I think. It makes a localized physics field so you can move around on any surface even if its spinning or moving at light speed and you won't be affected by the outside world. Extremely useful for moving spaceships and vehicles.

Comment: Going to give this a try today - it sounds perfect! :)

Comment: Update - works great. Flew around on a few contraptions while walking around without a problem. Fantastic!

Comment: Uploaded a Youtube video of the addon in action - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBrBsk7ZmMc.

Answer (score 5):

Actually standing on a moving object doesn't really work because Source isn't suitable for it. There are a number of things you can try. You can try spawning a seat, welding it to the vehicle and use it, for example. Alternatively, you can use this [Player Weld STOOL](http://www.garrysmod.org/downloads/?a=view&id=94498) to weld yourself to it, causing you to move along with it.

Comment: If it's a Source limitation then I guess there's no getting around it. That's a shame :(.